# Arduino Pushbutton Controlling VB6 shape fill color

Tags: arduino, vb6

I'm creating a program where if I click push button in Arduino the shape fill color in VB6 will change to red and if I click the pushbutton again the fill color will change to green. I am having problems reading serial data sent by my Arduino to VB6.

Here's my Arduino code:

```
int pbuttonPin = 7;// push button

int LED = 8; // LED

int val = 0; // push value from pin 2

int lightON = 0;//light status

int pushed = 0;//push status

void setup() 
{
Serial.begin(9600);

pinMode(pbuttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); 

pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);

}

void loop()
 {

  val = digitalRead(pbuttonPin);// read the push button value


  if(val == HIGH && lightON == LOW){

    pushed = 1-pushed;


    delay(100);

  }    

  lightON = val;

      if(pushed == HIGH)
     {
        Serial.print("Color Red\n");


        digitalWrite(LED, LOW); 


        delay(100);
       
      }
else
      {
        Serial.print("Color Green\n");


        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);


        delay(100);
      }
   
}
```

Here's my VB6 code,

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    With MSComm1
        .CommPort = 8
        .Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
        .Handshaking = comRTS
        .RTSEnable = True
        .DTREnable = True
        .RThreshold = 1
        .SThreshold = 1
        .InputMode = comInputModeText
        .InputLen = 0
        .PortOpen = True
    End With
    
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

    If MSComm1.Input = "Color Red" Then
        Shape1.FillColor = vbRed
        Shape1.FillStyle = vbSolid
    End If

    If MSComm1.Input = "Color Green" Then
        Shape1.FillColor = vbGreen
        Shape1.FillStyle = vbSolid
    End If

End Sub
```

Thank you very much for offering your assistance on the upcoming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee the data from the serial port will not be broken down into multiple parts so you should implement a buffer to keep track of all the parts received. Also, since `MSComm1.Input` [returns and removes characters from the receive buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa259393(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), your second `If` statement will never contain any data. You should read the data once and store it in a variable. Here's some code that implements this:

```
Dim m_sBuffer As String

Private Sub Form_Load()

    ' Initialize Serial Port
    With MSComm1
        .CommPort = 8
        .Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
        .Handshaking = comRTS
        .RTSEnable = True
        .DTREnable = True
        .RThreshold = 1
        .SThreshold = 1
        .InputMode = comInputModeText
        .InputLen = 0
        .PortOpen = True
    End With
    
    ' Initialize FillStyle
    Shape1.FillStyle = vbSolid
        
    ' Clear buffer
    m_sBuffer = ""
    
    ' Start timer
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Dim sReceivedData As String
    
    ' Read data from serial port
    sReceivedData = MSComm1.Input
    
    ' Append Received Data to buffer
    m_sBuffer = m_sBuffer & sReceivedData
    
    ' Check buffer content
    Select Case m_sBuffer
        Case "Color Red"
            Shape1.FillColor = vbRed
            m_sBuffer = "" ' Clear buffer
        Case "Color Green"
            Shape1.FillColor = vbGreen
            m_sBuffer = "" ' Clear buffer
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: In addition to the above, I'd first turn off handshaking altogether (comNone).  I'd also use much simpler messages - how about "R" and "G"?  That way, there's never any question of the buffer being broken up, so parsing would be simpler and more reliable.  Even if you have a lot of buttons you want to handle, you can get up to 63 using distinct characters for each state (on/off).  Furthermore, I think I'd move the toggle logic to the VB6 side - that way you could support up to 126 individual buttons (more than an entire PC keyboard).

Comment: I would also suggest using the `OnComm` event and handle case where the `MSComm` control's `CommEvent` property is `comEvReceive` instead of using a `Timer`. This will make the shape color change immediately instead of waiting for the timer event.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Étienne's use of the OnComm event - I didn't notice that the logic was polling with the timer.  Not that it would matter much, but this will also keep the CPU loading a bit less.